# How to set the developer team in a Multi-OS project?

Tags: ios, android-studio

I'm getting this error when I tried to run an Multi-OS Engine project:

```
###########
# ERROR LOG
###########

Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/softtim/Documents/FirstMultiOS/iOS/build/moe/xcodebuild/Debug-iphoneos
    DSTROOT = /Users/softtim/Documents/FirstMultiOS/iOS/build/moe/xcodebuild/dst
    MOE_GRADLE_EXTERNAL_BUILD = YES
    OBJROOT = /Users/softtim/Documents/FirstMultiOS/iOS/build/moe/xcodebuild/obj
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO
    SDKROOT = iphoneos10.2
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/softtim/Documents/FirstMultiOS/iOS/build/moe/xcodebuild/shared_precomps
    SYMROOT = /Users/softtim/Documents/FirstMultiOS/iOS/build/moe/xcodebuild/sym

=== BUILD TARGET HelloWorld OF PROJECT HelloWorld WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
Signing for "HelloWorld" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

** BUILD FAILED **
```

I already checked issues in internet but I can figure out how to set the development team. I created a default.properties file  as this answer say: https://discuss.multi-os-engine.org/t/how-to-configure-the-development-team-id-with-moe-1-2-0/237

But there's doesn't explain the format of that file, I  just have a file with these line inside:

```
developmentTeam=XXXXXXXXXX
```

(I'm not posting my current development team id)

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide your developers account credentials for XCode.

Go to XCode -> Preferences -> Accounts and add your Apple ID of your developers account.

Also you have to set your team at Project properties -> General -> Signing check there check box for "Automatically manage signing" and select your Team from dropdown list near Team label.

After it try to compile your application and XCode will create certificates for you.

Comment: Do you mean that Multi-OS Engine automatically recovers data from Xcode?
I have already established my credentials and my team of developers in Xcode. I have Xcode 8 installed, at the end of the documentation of the page multi os get started says something about it: https://multi-os-engine.org/start/